# Refrigerator water valve from wall is not dispensing water

Tags: water, refrigerator, valve

I had a repair man come to check my refrigerator for a repair and the cost was more than a new refrigerator, so I did just that bought a new fridge.  When replacing the old one the water shutoff valve from behind the refrigerator the wall was very stiff, but I was able to shut the water off.  I now connected the new refrigerator and nothing is dispensing. it doesn't seem like the wall valve is dispensing any water almost like its stuck in the closed position.  I removed the fridge line and opened the valve from the wall and no water comes out or drips out at all.  I looked under the nearby cabinets and under my sink and can not find another water shut off valve anywhere.  What should I do next?  I can try and move my old refrigerator back to the kitchen to see if its the new refrigerator, but I don't think so since no water comes out of the valve when it is opened.

Comment: I live in Florida so no basements to speak of.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's clear that you have a problem with the valve, or something before it, but there's no way we could tell from here; perhaps with more info? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: If you want detailed info about your particular valve situation, you will need to post a photo of the valve.

Answer (score 1):

The valve at the wall may not be the problem at all even though it was stiff. I have on quite a few occasions found water supply lines for refrigerators and ice machines connected using a saddle valve the type that you strap around a pipe and it punches a hole in the pipe, this is where I find the problem much of the time the tiny opening gets blocked or corroded and the water stops flowing, I usually turn off the water cut the pipe and install a T with a 1/4” fitting and valve reconnect the waterline and things work again. Copper and pvc/cpvc are easy with galvanized shark bite fittings do the job , I don’t use the saddle valves because they always fail in time and it is usually a leak, only sometimes no water.

Comment: That reminds me of “water quality “ which is big issue where I live. +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not uncommon for these small valves to fail in various ways. You need to trace the line back to its source and find a valve that shuts down the whole line so you can repair/replace the valve that failed, even if this means shutting water off to the whole house.

It is well for you to know where the source is and how to shut the line down from upstream because sometimes the opposite happens, uncontrollable water that will not shut off, i.e. flooded kitchen.